# Is there an app/plugin combination that suits the tracking of a public bus

Tags: javascript, android, php

In a town near where I live there is a public bus that runs a circuit about once an hour.

I was asked if it would be easy to track the bus (presumably via an android device on the bus) and put the location on a website. The idea is that there would be a URL on a sticker at each bus stop so that people could look up the position of the bus on their phones and see if it had passed yet.

I'm convinced that this is an easy use case - but my Google-Fu has turned up nothing.  Is this something that there is an existing framework for?

Answer (score 1):

This can be relatively simple for very small scale systems (e.g., one route and bus), but gets more complex as more buses and routes are introduced.

First, you need an app on a device to send vehicle position data - from this post on the onebusaway-developers group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/onebusaway-developers/JzYMwLFCpT0

> See this post from Kurt Raschke on associated challenges:
>   https://kurtraschke.com/2011/03/smartphones-for-avl
>
> See this post on the TransiTime group for some experimental work there in crowd-sourcing position data:
>   https://groups.google.com/d/msg/transitime/w_JZkt3sUVI/uMrq7LX_DQAJ

Some people have tested this concept (see above), but I'm not personally aware of any open-source apps readily available that do this.

Then, you need server-side software to convert those positions into a standardized format for vehicle positions, and estimated arrival times, if you want those - common formats are General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS)-realtime and SIRI - the best tool to my knowledge for this is the open-source project [TransiTime](http://www.transitime.org/).

Then, you need to provide this info in a format that can be easily viewed on smartphones.  I believe Transitime has some display functionality, but you'll probably want to check out [OneBusAway](http://onebusaway.org/), which has native apps on all smartphone platforms, and supports GTFS-realtime and SIRI as server-side input formats.